# "La konstruaĵo estas proksime / proksima de mi" -- Adverbo aŭ Adjektivo?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

En unu el la lecionoj de *Lernu*, estas ĉi tiu gramatik-noto:

> Oni uzas la **a**-finaĵon por priskribi substantivojn, sed kiam mankas substantivo oni uzas la **e**-finaĵon.
>
> *La vetero estas tre varm**a**.* (La vorto vetero estas la substantivo en la frazo.)
> *Estas tre varm**e**.* (Mankas substantivo en la frazo.)

Post la noto estas multaj ekzemplo-frazoj. Unu el ili estas la frazo en la titolo:

> La konstruaĵo estas proksim**a**. ==> La konstruaĵo estas proskim**e** de mi.

Mi supozas, ke tiu ekzemplo estas eraro. La substantivo (*konstruaĵo*) ekzistas en ambaŭ frazoj, kaj nur la aldono de *de mi* al *proksim-*, ne estas sufiĉa kaŭzo por ke la gramatik-funkcio de *proksim-* ŝanĝiĝu.

Ĉu tio malĝustas? (Kial?)

Answer (score 6):

La ekzemplo ne estas eraro, nur la klarigo estas iomete nekompleta.
Ja veras, ke adjektivoj rilatas al substantivoj (kaj substantivecaĵoj: pronomoj, citaĵoj, rilataj subfrazoj), sed ankaŭ adverbo povas priskribi substantivon.

La decidiga distingo estas, kiun rolon plenumas la priskriba vorto. Tiun rolon oni povas videbligi demandante pri la koncerna vorto:

> **Kie** estas la konstruaĵo? - Ĝi estas proksim**e**.
>
> **Kia** estas la konstruaĵo? - Ĝi estas proksim**a**.

En la unua frazo la adverbo montras la lokon de la konstruaĵo, en la dua, la adjektivo nomas kvaliton de ĝi, nome proksimecon. En la praktiko, ambaŭ frazoj havas la saman signifon, sed oni povus elpensi ekzemplojn, kie ambaŭ* funkcioj kontrastas, ekz. (kun metafora kaj laŭvorta signifoj):

> Ĉiuj amikoj, kiujn mi povus nomi proksimaj [kvalito], estas malproksime. [loko]

*Same oni povas demandi pri tempo, ekz.:

> **Kiam** li estos en la stacidomo? - Li estos fru**e**.

Comment: Do la adjektivo proksima (aŭ iu simila adjektivo) neniam taŭgas por paroli pri loko? Adjektivoj povas priskribi lokaj rilatoj en ĉiuj aliaj lingvoj, kiujn mi scias

Comment: Tion mi ne asertis. Kion mi diris, validas por la predikativa uzo, dum kiel atribuaĵo ankaŭ la loka signifo povas alpreni adjektivan formon: _ĉiuj proksimaj domoj_ [loko aŭ kvalito], forma akordigo ĉi tie pli gravas ol enhava (tipologie atentinda fenomeno]. Ja eblas tamen atribuigi adverbon kiel adjunkton al substantivo, post ĝin: _la domoj ĉi tie/en la ĉirkaŭaĵo/proksime estas belaj_.